# Django about Different templates have different results

Tags: django

I'm a super newbie, so please refer to this and read it.

I am creating a bulletin board that communicates by DB <> API <> WEB method.

Successfully import comments with comment.html.
However, comments cannot be imported at {%inlude%} in boardapi_detail.html.

Please refer to the picture at the bottom of the article.

view.py

```
class Commentapi_list(generic.TemplateView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {
        'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
    }

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/boardapi/'  + str(data['pk']) + '/comment/'
    datas = requests.get(url, params=data).json()

    # print(datas)
    # print(type(datas))

    df = pd.DataFrame(datas)

    clist = [tuple(r) for r in df.to_numpy()]
    print(clist)
    # print(type(clist))

    return render(self.request, 'comment_form.html', {
        'comment_list' : clist
    })
```

urls.py

```
path('board/<int:pk>/', views.Boardapi_detail.as_view(), name="board_detail")
```

comment.html

```
{% if not comment_list %}
<p class="text-center"> There is no comment. </p>
{% endif %}

<div style="margin:20px 0;">
{% for i in comment_list %}
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tbl_replist" id="reply_list_layer">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;border-top: 1px solid #eee;width: 114px;">{{ i.1 }}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 0;">{{ i.2 }}
                <span style="color: #999;font-size: 11px;display: block;">{{ i.3 }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% if user.username == i.c_writer or user.is_staff %}
            <a href="/board/{{ i.0 }}/delete/" class="btn btn-outline-success">delete</a>
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

boardapi_detail.html

```
{% if not board_detail %}
                <p class="text-center">There's nothing. </p>
            {% else %}
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
                        <td width="20%" align="center">title</td>
                        <td width="80%" align="left">{{ board_detail.b_title }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
                        <td width="20%" align="center">writer</td>
                        <td width="80%" align="left">{{ board_detail.b_writer }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
                        <td width="20%" align="center">note</td>
                        <td width="80%" align="left">{{ board_detail.b_note }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
                        <td width="20%" align="center">time</td>
                        <td width="80%" align="left">{{ board_detail.b_date }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:60px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;" align="center">
                        <td width="100%" colspan="2">
                            <a href="/board/{{ board_detail.b_no }}/edit/" class="btn btn-outline-success">edit</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-right:10px;" onclick="location.href='/board/'">list</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
                            <td width="20%" align="center">comment</td>
                            <td width="80%" align="left">({{ board.comment_set.all.count }})</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                {% endif %}

                {% include "comment.html" %}
```

The pictures below are about the first article each.

comment.html page
[image]

**↑Successfully imported all 3 comments.**

boardapi_detail.html page
[image]
**↑couldn't get even one comment.**

Comment: You need the comments data in Boardapi_detail view

Comment: @JailtonSilva you mean boardapi_detail.html need the comments data? How should I do?

Comment: The url you provide is called Boardapi_detail, I assumed that this view will render at the end boardapi_detail.html (this in turn includes comment.html). The comment data is currently in Commentapi_list, which is never called. you need to send this data via Boardapi_detail

Comment: when you code ```{% include "comment.html" %}``` this includes the html. The data must come from the view.

Comment: @JailtonSilva Thanks to your teaching, I succeeded. I also had boardapi_detail view get the comment data and put it in the render context. It works good.

Comment: @JailtonSilva Is there a way to count the number of comments I received? {{ comment_list.all.count }}I tried it this way, but it doesn't work. I don't think I'm looking for anything even if I search it. Should I solve this in the view, not in the template?